# Loading data to Ext.FormPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a store and FormPanel. And i want to show data from store in panel.
If i do this:

```
 var store_form=null;
 store_form = new Ext.data.Store({                
        url: url_servlet+"kadastr_zemform.jsp",
        reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
        totalProperty: "results", 
        record: "contact",
                        fields: [
       ]}),
       listeners: {
         'load' :  function(store_form,records,options) {
                   this.loaded = true;
                   var record = store_form.getAt(0);
                   podform.getForm().loadRecord(record);
               }
           }
    });    

});
store_form.load();
```

All froms fine.

But if i call loadRecord() in formPanel's listener i get error:

```
TypeError: store_form.getAt is not a function
(624 out of range 31)
```

My code.

```
var podform = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelAlign: 'left',
    id: 'tab_6',
    frame:true,
    title: 'Договоры подряда',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 600,
    listeners: {
        'activate' :  function(store_form,records,options) {
        console.log("store:"+store_form);
        this.loaded = true;
        //alert("loaded");
        //console.log(store.getAt(0));
        var record = store_form.getAt(0);
        podform.getForm().loadRecord(record);
        }
    },
            fields[]
 });
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: store_form is a form panel. Its not a store. so it doesnot contain any such method.

Comment: Dont understand you. `store_form = new Ext.data.Store({ `

Comment: you have used **store_form** variable in the activate listener of form panel. But this variable is a form panel **this** parameter for the activate listener. if you want to use this variable, just change the variable name in the activate listener to some other variable.

Comment: Im delete line `this.loaded = true;`. Nothing change.

Comment: try this...


listeners: { 'activate' : function(form,records,options) { this.loaded = true; //alert("loaded"); //console.log(store.getAt(0)); var record = store_form.getAt(0); podform.getForm().loadRecord(record); }

Comment: Yeah really this works. Please convert your comment to answer and i accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
 listeners: { 'activate' : function(form,records,options)
 { 
   this.loaded = true; 
   var record = store_form.getAt(0); 
   podform.getForm().loadRecord(record);
 }
```